# Find the missing integer (i) , The duplicated integer (j), the length or random integers (n). But only if "i" = "j", just tell me "Huh!?"

Tags: code-golf

## The task

Your program will be given the following inputs: a number *n*, and an array of *n* positive integers. Your program only has to work when *n*=1000.

The program must do the following:

- If the input array is a permutation of the range [1, 2, …, *n*], output `Huh!?`
- Otherwise, return a three-element array [*i*, *j*, *n*], where *i* is a number from 1 to *n* inclusive that does not appear in the input array, and *j* is a number that appears more than once in the input array.

## Clarifications

- Because *n* will always have the same value, your program may get at it three different ways: hardcoding it as 1000, checking the length of the input array, or taking it from input.
- Per PPCG rules, you don't have to read an input at all if you don't need it to solve the question.
- The input will always be chosen so that there's a unique answer (in other words, the input array will contain no more than one duplicated element).

## Test case generator

The following test case generator, in the statistical programming language R, will generate an appropriate test case for this challenge. It takes the following inputs:

1. The value of *n*. In order to create an appropriate test case, this should be 1000.
2. The value of *i*.
3. The value of *j*.

Here's the generator itself:

```r
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript 
#Random_number_generator_1.R
getwd()

printf <- function(...) cat(sprintf(...))
print("Please set the range of random numbers from 1 to n \n")

this_range = scan(file = 'stdin', what = integer(), nmax = 1)

numbers = 1:this_range

#print("How many random numbers in this range")
# random_numbers = scan(file = "", what = integer(), n = 1)

#if(random_numbers > this_range)
#{
#  remove(random_numbers)
#  print("Sorry. When Replace = FALSE. It's not possible to have more unique random numbers than the given range")
#}

random_numbers = sample(numbers)
random_numbers = sample(random_numbers)

print("Now remove any random number in the available range")
number_taken = scan(file = 'stdin' , what = integer(), nmax = 1)
random_numbers = random_numbers[random_numbers != number_taken]

print("Now insert any random number within the range")
number_inserted = scan(file = 'stdin', what = integer(), nmax = 1)

random_numbers = append(random_numbers, number_inserted)

print(random_numbers)

write(random_numbers, file = "my_random_numbers.txt", sep = " ")
```

## Victory condition

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes wins!

Comment: I almost solved this problem completely with 580 bytes of an R-script.

Comment: Please explain the dislike? I provided all details that you need to solve this problem including the desired output, and that the problem is truly solvable.

Comment: The question is too long. Delete the unrelated part, and move the most important part to the top, while keeping the rest as appendix, and outsource long programs to pastebin.

Comment: So it's a good question. You just don't like how it's formatted? What do you consider unrelated exactly? The last time my question was put on hold for being too vague, and now it's too exact? How does that work?

Comment: Does the "space separated input" add anything to the challenge or could we just take a list?

Comment: when would `i = j` not be the same as `j = i`?

Comment: It would always be the same. I was just trying to be extra clear about it.

Comment: @xyz123 the balance between concision and precision is not always an easy one.

Comment: If you can read space separated input into a list, then it's fine.

Comment: What's up with the strict output formatting?

Comment: It's for human readability.

Comment: "If you can read space separated input into a list, then it's fine." does not really answer my question - I wanted to know if I may take input as a list? Also do we need to output a space separated string or is my current `[j, i, n]` OK? Note that usually IO is kept loose in code-golf to allow us to concentrate on the core of the challenge unless a tight I/O adds to the challenge in some way.

Comment: [i, j, n] is fine since everyone understand my question. You can change the format of my question to a way that makes sense to you, so long as you don't dislike my thoughtful question in the process.

Comment: @xyz123, next time you post, you may want to use [the sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges) first.

Comment: I actually got suggestions form sandbox to modify my question, and I modified it appropriately, and then I got all this hate from you guys, and you put my question on hold again, so yeah, I don't know what you want from me!

Comment: I don't think it should have been put on hold (especially after I improved the formatting), but at that point it already had 4 votes to place it on hold, so only 1 more was needed. I've started a vote to reopen it again. In general, Stack Exchange's close and reopen system is problematic because if someone thinks a post shouldn't be placed on hold, they have no way to express that opinion until after it already is.

Comment: Do we really have to output `n` given that it's always 1000? Also, outputting "Huh?" as an alternative to a list of numbers is not possible in strongly-typed languages and IMO a needless complication. I think this would be a good challenge if not for the extra stuff.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>27 26  21</s> 18 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

-8 bytes by applying a suggestion from Leaky Nun (use multi-set difference to `J` and a dequeue to replace a length-1 test)

```
ḲµVœ^J;LµḊȧȯ“Huh!?
```

A full program.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DY@9SoQxFERf5egTJLk/ucHCVsTa0k4Q2dbCztrW1t5SEBa2XhD2NdYX@RwIYcKduXPy/LjbvW7b@fBz3N//fjzcXt0d9@fD@@nr9P339nnz8nRxvW3bZQZR9MUcWGNJJGMyjW7MSRXWsSSdaoRRAx@spDqRrKAIpRe9s5TQDicnPunaTRYVTAktVVJHomGGMRyTVaUK452emBoWId0aZeRgNCahClHIEKjeGcHSIPCg6xaIs4Sr25myTzJx4SxWMdQnOn1DlaSMSohfr0Y21COQwuUbiFnjdvkP)**

#### How?

```
ḲµVœ^J;LµḊȧȯ“Huh!? - Main link: list of characters
Ḳ                  - split at spaces, call this x
 µ                 - start a new monadic chain with the result of that on the left
  V                - evaluate as Jelly code (vectorises) -> list of integers
     J             - range(length(x)) -> [1,2,3,...,n]
   œ^              - multi-set difference -> one of: []; [i,j]; or [j,i]
       L           - length of x -> n
      ;            - concatenate -> one of: [n]; or [i, j, n]; or [j, i, n]
        µ          - new monadic chain, call that r
         Ḋ         - dequeue r -> one of: []; [j, n]; or [i, n]
          ȧ        - logical and with r -> []; [i, j, n]; or [j, i, n]
            “Huh!? - list of characters "Huh!?" (end of a program so no close quote needed)
           ȯ       - logical or -> one of "Huh!?"; [i, j, n]; or [j, i, n]
                   - implicit print
```

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica, 70 bytes

```
{(a=(Range@1000~Complement~#)[[1]])+Tr@#-500500,a,1000}~Check~"Huh!?"&
```

Anonymous function. Takes a list of numbers as input and returns a list of numbers or a string as output. Ignore any messages generated. Works by finding *j* and then computing *i*.

Comment: That's pretty neat.